# How to plot yticks on right side and keep the classic left side

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot some data and add a ytick on it on the right side but when I am doing it, the left side ticks disappear and i want to keep it. Can someone help me please ? I have seen other posts on this but they are all using `ax.` commands and I am not familiar with this, I am only using `plt.` functions.

I used these commands:

```
plt.yticks([seuil1,seuil2],["20%","20%"])
plt.tick_params(axis='y',labelleft=False,labelright=True)
```

Plot without yticks:
[image: Plot without yticks]

Plot with yticks right side:
[image: Plot with yticks right side]

As you can see, the left side disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the difference between using `plt` and `ax` these are two different styles of using matplotlib; they are pyplot and object-oriented styles respectively.

With pyplot-style matplotlib creates and manages the figures and axes, you use `plt.` functions to manipulate them.

With object-oriented style you explicitly create your figure and axes (`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`) and then call methods on either the `fig` or `ax` to manipulate them. This is the approach I have taken in my example.

Take a look at the [matplotlib usage guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#usage-guide) and their [tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html) to get an idea of how you can create and customise your plots.

---

Here you want to use [`twinx`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) to create another axis that shares the x-axis allowing you to position other yticks on the right y-axis. I have commented above each line with what it is that line is doing.

```py
# Create a figure and ax
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Get data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
y = 1 / x

# Plot the data
ax.plot(x, y, label=r"$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$")
# Place legend
ax.legend(loc="upper right")

# Create a second y-axis
y2 = ax.twinx()
# Copy the y limits from the left axis
y2.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
# Set the right y-yick positions
y2.set_yticks([2, 6])
# Set the right y-tick labels
y2.set_yticklabels(["A", "B"])
```

Which produces:

[image: Graph of y = 1/x with right tick labels]

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Alex answer...

If you don't need ticks, try:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Create a figure and ax
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Get data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
y = 1 / x

# Plot the data
ax.plot(x, y, label=r"$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$")

vals = [2, 6]
labs = ['A', 'B']
for val, lab in zip(vals, labs):
    ax.text(1.02, val, lab, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())

plt.show()
```

If you *do* need ticks, rather than making a twin axes you can also create a secondary axes:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# Create a figure and ax
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Get data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
y = 1 / x

# Plot the data
ax.plot(x, y, label=r"$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$")

vals = [2, 6]
labs = ['A', 'B']

secax = ax.secondary_yaxis(1.0)
secax.set_yticks(vals)
secax.set_yticklabels(labs)

plt.show()
```

Comment: These are both good solutions! Though I would advocate using `ax.secondary_yaxis("right")` for clarity!